# Delphi 11 theme export

Tags: delphi, themes

I have recently installed RAD Studio 11 on a new VM.  I have a huge active project in Delphi 10.2 in a different VM, that among other things uses themes.  Migrating the D10.2 project to D11 is not an option right now.  But I'd like to export the Windows 11 themes from the D11 IDE to use in the D10.2 project if that's possible.  So far I haven't found a way to do the export.  Am I missing something in the IDE, or is a 3rd-party tool available to do this?  Or are the theme definitions in files stuck off in a folder somewhere that I'm not finding?  Thanks.

Comment: Likely not possible since the most modern themes probably use features that were introduced after 10.2. Just stick with the old themes or migrate the project. Also it's a worry that your projects live in VMs rather than revision control systems.

Comment: David - The project files are in our corporate RCS.  The IDEs are in separate VMs.  But the D10.2 project depends on several commercial 3rd-party libs (TMS, Prosys Sentrol, etc.) and department budget considerations makes spending for upgrades on those not in the cards right now, so migrating the project to D11 is going to have to wait.

Comment: The Windows 11 styles from D11 are version 2.0 styles, while D10.2 may be limited to version 1.0 styles only.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the downloaded .zip files containing the styles for D11 are stored in `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\<style name>`, and the .vsf files from them are copied to the `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Styles` folder for D10.2.  Restart the IDE and they show up in the list of available styles.

However, as David and Uwe noted, they don't work 100% as-is.  They *almost* do - everything appears to work fine except forms with borderstyles that include a non-client title bar.  On those forms, there's a large "X" in the middle of the title bar and a off-color square box on the left of that title bar underneath the form's icon (or underneath the title text for toolwindows without an icon.)  Also, a few 3rd-party controls aren't quite right (TMS TAdvSpinEdits paint their up/down arrows wrong, etc.)  These may be fixable with one of the style editors out there, or at least give a basis from which to create a new style .vsf that's D10.2 compatible.  Or I can spend the money to get the D10.2 W11 styles pre-done from one of the styles vendors.